# How to use Pytorch pretrained model (.pth)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, resnet

https://github.com/ZJULearning/resa
I have used above GitHub repo, for lane detection, it contains already pretrained model for lane Detection on CULane dataset.
I wanted to use this pretrained model and test it on other data, but I am not sure, how to approach.

On loading data `model = torch.load('culane_resnet50.pth', map_location=torch.device('cpu'))`
it is loaded succesfully.

but on using `model.eval()`
it is showing an error " 'dict' object has no attribute 'eval' "

On printing model `print(model)`
the output is something like this

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdu1C.png)

I want to know what the model represents, Also is it possible to use this pretrained model to make prediction on new data sets and if yes, how?

Comment: maybe you should dig in source of `resa` to see how it loads model. It may need to add class with model structure. OR see Torch documentation [Saving and Loading Models — PyTorch Tutorials 1.12.1+cu102 documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html). It shows: `checkpoint = torch.load(PATH)` and later `model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model_state_dict'])` but first it needs `model = TheModelClass(...)`

Comment: yeah, I am not getting it, why we need model class in the first place, then what is the need of pre-trained model. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: it seems it doesn't keep full (pre-trained) model but only array with weights from pre-trained model. And this may need original class with model structure (not pre-trained model) to set weights in this model and reconstruct pre-trained model. But it seems all `resa` has very complex code for this.

Comment: in source code I found [load_network_specified](https://github.com/ZJULearning/resa/blob/6740654680eb50ddf2f760aa7cfba3f498997be7/runner/net_utils.py#L23) which probably loads your file - but it needs also some `net` to rebuild `neural network`. It needs to find `load_network_specified` in full code to see what is this `net`.

Comment: does this means, I cant use the pretrained model independently and I need to have that model class architecture.

Comment: it means they created very complex system to load model and it is hard to do it separatelly.

Comment: @furas thank you for your time. I'll dig deep and will try to find any alternate soultion.